# Swift returns error "Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type '[NSLayoutConstraint]'"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I got this error message after upgrade with Xcode 6.2 to Xcode 7.0.1.

```
/Users/ZERO/Documents/Xcode/XXXXX/Library/SegmentedControl/SegmentedControl.swift:161:36: Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type '[NSLayoutConstraint]'
```

My code

```
let constraints = mainView.constraints()
```

Comment: Did you look up "constraints" in the UIView documentation? It is a *property*, not a method.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is reported if you are using Swift 1.2 code on Xcode 7.x.

[image: Screenshot 1]
I got this issue for UITableViewCell shown below :

```
let cells = tableView.visibleCells()
```

You can fix this by simply removing '()' parentheses as show below :

```
 let cells = tableView.visibleCells
```

In your case it should be

```
 let constraints = mainView.constraints
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to execute an array as if it was a method, `constraints` is no longer a method, it is now a property of type`[NSLayoutConstraint]`. Remove your `()` to fix the error.